# Can we generate a pdf report using karate

Tags: pdf, karate

I am using Karate and currently my framework generates a HTML report. However, I want to generate a pdf report instead of HTML.

Is it possible in Karate or any plugins suggestion which could be integrated so as to generate pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to you. Karate outputs the Cucumber JSON format - and in fact does not have built-in HTML reports (for the parallel runner) and teams typically use 3rd party plugins such as this one: https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting

So it is up to you to find a suitable PDF reporter - or you can write one yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Peter. Can you please elaborate a bit as i m new to this.

Comment: @user1873274 I don't know how I can make my answer above any clearer, try reading the docs also: https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution